# If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x>0$, $x+n\in\mathbb{N}$ imply $x\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers

So another easy question. The title is Theorem (1.17) from [Stromberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470425440) part (iii). I know there are easier arguments to prove this, but I would like to understand the author's reasoning.

To prove (iii) he uses induction. For the basis step, if $n=1$ and $x+n\in\mathbb{N}$, then by (ii) [already proved] $x+1-1\in\mathbb{N}$, or $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Why it is so obvious from this statement that $x=1$? (It could well be 2,3,etc.)

Comment: Why do the basis step as $n=1$? If you do it for $n=0$ then it is obvious since $x+0=0$.

Comment: Ah thanks for the remark, because he's assuming $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Note that $x+1\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x+1>1$ since $x>0$. Then (ii) says that $x=(x+1)-1\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes I can see this, but why if $x\in\mathbb{N}$ implies $x=1$?

Comment: There isn't an $x=1$ written in the whole proof. Maybe your book has a typo somewhere.

Comment: Ah I see the problem, the only thing that $x\in\mathbb{N}$ does is to show that. $1\in T$, where $T = \lbrace n\in\mathbb{N} : \rm (iii) holds\rbrace$  .